# Adding Watermark/Text in Videos in Java

Tags: java, video, text, ffmpeg, watermark

I am looking for adding texts and watermarks in video files (in java) using the libraries. The texts/Watermark can be single line/multi-line and at different intervals.
I didn't find any open source tool or java library which helps me to achieve the goal.

Comment: Refer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789476/java-jsp-how-to-add-watermark-on-video

Comment: Hi Vishal, I want to add texts(Single-Line,Multi-Line) as well in the video and multiple water-mark inputs [a text/image with different start-end time capsules]. These are not mentioned in the above shared link.

Comment: Kindly, go through the open source tool mentioned in that link. There is an issue for the same you asked for, https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/issues/271